# First radio button inside *ngFor requires two clicks to show selected

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Edit: The "searching..." and moving the elements has something to do with it. If I remove it, it works great on the first search. then if I search again, I have to click twice on every new element to select them. Below is a video without the searching. I move the mouse off the button and back on if I have to click it twice

[image: edit-demo]]

I have an ion-radio-group where some elements come from a *ngFor. When the first item is selected, the value of the form changes (I tested that the value is changed on the form correctly, and you can see the submit button becomes clickable with the right value). But, the radio is not checked. This only happens on the first item. In the below demo you will see I click the radio (the submit button becomes enabled), then on the second click, it selects the radio visually.

The other two radios both select on the first click.

[image: demo]]

Here is the HTML:

```
 <ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-label>{{ message }}</ion-label>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input color="primary" formControlName="search" placeholder="city or address"></ion-input>
      <ion-button (click)="searchClicked()" fill="clear"
        ><ion-icon onclick="searchClicked()" name="search" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon
      ></ion-button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group formControlName="radio" (ionSelect)="radioSelected($event)">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults; let i = index">
          <ion-radio value="{{ i }}" margin-end></ion-radio>
          <ion-label>{{ searchResult.name }}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-grid class="double-padding-start">
          <ion-row align-items-center>
            <ion-radio value="city" margin-end></ion-radio>
            <ion-select okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" formControlName="city">
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
                {{ city.name }}
              </ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-radio-group>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-button
      (click)="dismiss()"
      [disabled]="!form.valid"
      fill="clear"
      class="button-padding-start large"
      margin
      >Submit</ion-button
    >
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the code requested:

```
  radioSelected($event: CustomEvent) {
    const details: RadioChangeEventDetail = $event.detail;
    const result = this.getResult(details.value);
    if (result) {
      this.changed.emit(result);
    }
  }

  getResult(radio?: string): SortAndFilter['searchResult'] | undefined {
    if (!this.form) return;
    const radioValue: string = radio ? radio : this.form.controls.radio.value;
    let result: SortAndFilter['searchResult'];

    if (radioValue === 'city') {
      const cityId = this.form.value.city;
      if (this.cities) {
        const city: City | undefined = this.cities.find(searchedCity => searchedCity.id === cityId);
        if (city) {
          result = {
            lat: city.lat,
            lng: city.lng,
            zoom: city.zoom,
            name: city.name,
          };
        }
      }
    } else {
      const index = Number(radioValue.split(',')[0]);
      if (typeof index === 'number' && this.searchResults.length > index) {
        result = {
          lat: this.searchResults[index]!.lat,
          lng: this.searchResults[index]!.lng,
          zoom: 12,
          name: this.searchResults[index]!.name,
        };
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

This is also run when the search is clicked:

```
  searchClicked() {
    if (!this.form) return;
    const searchTerm = this.form.controls.search.value;
    if (!searchTerm) return;
    this.searchStatus = 'searching';
    this.mapService.loadSdk().subscribe(loaded => {
      if (loaded) {
        this.mapService.lookupLocation(searchTerm).then(results => {
          if (results.length === 0) {
            this.searchStatus = `${searchTerm} not found`;
            this.searchResults = [];
          } else {
            this.searchResults = results;
            this.searchStatus = undefined;
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.searchStatus = undefined;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the complete HTML for the form.

Comment: Added the HTML cgTag

Comment: How is the text "Searching..." displayed on the form?

Comment: Details added to original post at the top. Searching... was put in as an element in the array and then removed. I tested taking that feature out. It definitely has to do with changing the form after it is made. Now, it works on the first click, but if I search again, it creates new issues. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the `radioSelected($event)` function.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the `value="{{ i }}"` for the radio button. Radio buttons appear to need unique values even if you are replacing the radio in the `*ngFor` to avoid this bug. I time stamped my indices to make them unique.

When a search is clicked I set the current time (ms) to a variable called time, then I set the radio to `value = "{{ time + i }}`. The time variable is subtracted to get the `i` when it's read.

Comment: I had this same problem, and this was the exact answer ! @Diesel

Comment: Thanks for the answer, same solution for Ionic + Vue too, I put the value of ion-radio with a combination of values that I know that will not be repeated, something like this: `<ion-radio slot="end" :value="itemInLoop.name + Math.random()"></ion-radio>`